# Binary string literals in Ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby, encoding

When upgrading to Ruby 2.0, a test case started to fail:

```
expected = "\xD1\x9B\x86"
assert_equal expected, actual
```

with the following message:

```
<"ћ\x86"> expected but was
<"\xD1\x9B\x86">.
```

The `actual` variable contains a binary string obtained from an external library call.

The problem is that the default encoding of source files (and therefore string literals) [changed in Ruby 2.0](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6679) from US-ASCII to UTF-8.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The solution is to change the definition of the string literal to enforce its encoding. There are a few possible options to do this:

Use [Array#pack](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Array%3apack) (all versions of Ruby):

```
expected = ["d19b86"].pack('H*')
```

Use [String#b](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/2.0.0/String%3ab) (Ruby >= 2.0 only):

```
expected = "\xD1\x9B\x86".b
```

Use [String#force_encoding](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/String%3aforce_encoding) (Ruby >= 1.9 only):

```
expected = "\xD1\x9B\x86".force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT")
```

Comment: How the array#pack option clicked on your head? this pack & unpack is the hard part for me in ruby :( how to digest that any clue?

Comment: @RubyLovely: I already knew that pack/unpack existed for things like this, so I looked up the documentation and tried it out. That it returns a binary string makes sense, as it is designed specifically for processing binary data.

Comment: Hmm, I'm using exactly this String#force_encoding trick, but I get an error from some tools if the string is not valid UTF-8, which mostly defeats the purpose, since if I could have used UTF-8, I would have just typed in the Unicode characters. Pack will surely work though.