# Converting gsub() pattern from ruby 1.8 to 2.0

Tags: ruby, regex, unicode, gsub

I have a ruby program that I'm trying to upgrade form ruby 1.8 to ruby 2.0.0-p247.

This works just fine in 1.8.7:

```
 begin
   ARGF.each do |line|
     # a collection of pecluliarlities, appended as they appear in data
     line.gsub!("\x92", "'")
     line.gsub!("\x96", "-")
     puts line
   end
 rescue => e
   $stderr << "exception on line #{$.}:\n"
   $stderr << "#{e.message}:\n"
   $stderr << @line
 end
```

But under ruby 2.0, this results in this an exxeption when encountering the 96 or 92 encoded into a data file that otherwise contains what appears to be ASCII:

```
 invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

I have tried all manner of things: double backslashes, using a regex object instead of the string, force_encoding(), etc. and am stumped.

Can anybody fill in the missing puzzle piece for me?

Thanks.

=============== additions: 2013-09-25 ============

Changing \x92 to \u2019 did not fix the problem.

The program does not error until it actually hits a 92 or 96 in the input file, so I'm confused as to how the character pattern in the string is the problem when there are hundreds of thousands of lines of input data that are matched against the patterns without incident.

Answer (score 3):

It's not the regex that's throwing the exception, it's the Ruby compiler.  `\x92` and `\x96` are how you would represent `’` and `–` in the windows-1252 encoding, but Ruby expects the string to be UTF-8 encoded.  You need to get out of the habit of putting raw byte values like `\x92` in your string literals.  Non-ASCII characters should be specified by Unicode escape sequences (in this case, `\u2019` and `\u2013`).

It's a Unicode world now, stop thinking of text in terms of bytes and think in terms of characters instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Incidentally, how did you know that \x92 maps to \u2019?

Comment: Long and bitter experience. ;) For the specific translations I usually use Windows' Character Map applet or an encoding chart like [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

Comment: What if I were to force_encoding('windows-1252')? Would that keep my \xXZX patterns working?

Comment: You mean, as a stopgap? :D  I don't do Ruby, but that should work.  Check out [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15843684/20938) for some other options.

Comment: less as a stopgap, and more as a "requires fewer code changes". The whole this is goofy. the file will have ASCII hyphens and x96es in it on the same line. sigh.  I'll look at those suggestions in the q/a to which you linked.  Thanks very much.  I think I now have a paddle.